# Configuring Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine 2 + PhpUnit

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, phpunit

Start writing a new project in Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine 2, interested in the question of testing (PhpUnit), advise how best to configure. 
Or can you tell me the project on GitHub which used Zend Framework 2 + Doctrine 2 + PhpUnit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a new project, add a `composer.json` file with this:

```
composer init
```

Then answer some questions about the software you are going to write.

```
composer require zendframework/zendframework:~2.2
composer require doctrine/common:~2.4
composer require doctrine/dbal:~2.4
composer require doctrine/orm:~2.4
```

These commands add the software in at least the version behind the tilde, but trying to get the most recent version that does exist.

```
composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~3.7
```

This is for development and will only install PHPUnit when Composer is not called with `composer install --no-dev` (which is suggested if you want to deploy that copy live).

Done.

Comment: Wondering how to configure PHPunit to the wine database for Doctrine.

Comment: That's another question.